# How to use custom processor on spring cloud data flow?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Here is the Stream I intend to implement:

[image: Spring Cloud DataFlow Stream]

It is supposed to read records from jdbc, transform to json and write on another database thru jdbc.

For this I have implemented (using the new functional approach):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StreamAppApplication {
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(new ResultSetSerializer());

        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        SpringApplication.run(StreamAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<ResultSet, String> recordToJson() {
        return value -> {
            try {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Falha conversão json", e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

On the application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=recordToJson
```

Then I have imported it on the web UI as app of type TRANSFORM. It appeared on the UI with the transform classification and no parameters.

How do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review and follow the [function-bindings recipe](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.6.0.SNAPSHOT/recipes/functional-apps/scst-function-bindings/) from the Microsite to get an understanding of what needs explicitly configured.

From what I can tell, you're likely missing the binding configuration for how your custom processor needs to consume and produce to the relevant channels.

Perhaps even repeat the samples from the recipe on your environment to get an understanding of how it comes together. With that then, you will be able to adapt your custom processor in the same data pipeline to validate it.

Comment: Yes, in this case, what you would need are: `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings. recordToJson-in-0=input` and `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.recordToJson-out-0=output`. Here the `input` and `output` are the default names SCDF would look for binding your function app into the messaging system.